# How does the C strtol interpret hex strings?

Tags: c, hex, bit-manipulation, long-integer

I expect `strtol("ffffffffffffffff", NULL, 16)` to return `-1` and `strtol("7fffffffffffffff", NULL, 16)` to return `LONG_MAX`, since the [linux man-page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) first sentence seems to imply strtol returns signed long. The second call does return the expected result. But the first call returns `LONG_MAX`! Like, the input hex strings are not even the same. As if that's not confusing enough, `strtol("8000000000000000", NULL, 16)`, which I expect to return `LONG_MIN`, returns the same value as the previous two calls, `LONG_MAX`. For the previous two calls, I thought strtol was ignoring the most significant bit in the input string, but the third call refutes this hypothesis.

Is this some weird case of casting going on or I am mixing mathematical reality with C reality?

Here is my source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    long x = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 16);
    printf("%ld\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling with `gcc scratch.c` on Ubuntu, and I am getting my results by passing a hex string as a command line argument. For example:

```
./a.out ffffffffffffffff // gives LONG_MAX
./a.out 8000000000000000 // gives LONG_MAX
./a.out 7fffffffffffffff // gives LONG_MAX
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and exactly how you are observing what the results are.  Just saying what you are seeing is not enough -- we need to be convinced that you're not doing something that affects the "viewing" of the return value.

Comment: `ffffffffffffffff` and `8000000000000000` are to big to fit in a `long`, so `LONG_MAX` is returned.

Comment: What is the size of `long` in your system?

Comment: @NathanOliver I thought an 8-byte ```long``` would store those hex strings without overflow.

Comment: @Gerhardh It's 8 bytes. Confirmed with ```sizeof(long)```.

Comment: The input isnt expecting a binary representation.  When you do `ffffffffffffffff` you are asking for a value of `2^64 - 1`, which can't fit in a 64 bit wide signed integer.  If you want `-1`, you can use `-0x01`

Comment: `-8000000000000000` seems to work correctly.

Comment: Just use `strtoul` and `unsigned long`?

Answer (score 5):

`strtol("ffffffffffffffff", NULL, 16)` requests `strtol` to interpret “ffffffffffffffff” as a hexadecimal integer. It does not request `strtol` to interpret it as a specification of hexadecimal values for individual bytes and then to reinterpret those bytes as an encoding for a `long`.

The hexadecimal integer ffffffffffffffff<sub>16</sub> is 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 = 2<sup>64</sup>−1. In your C implementation, the largest value representable in a `long` is 9,223,372,036,854,775,808 = 2<sup>63</sup>−1.

The documentation for `strtol`, in C 2018 7.22.1.4 8, says that, if the value is above or below the range of representable values, `LONG_MAX` or `LONG_MIN`, respectively, is returned:

> The `strtol`, `strtoll`, `strtoul`, and `strtoull` functions return the converted value, if any. If no conversion could be performed, zero is returned. If the correct value is outside the range of representable values, `LONG_MIN`, `LONG_MAX`, `LLONG_MIN`, `LLONG_MAX`, `ULONG_MAX`, or `ULLONG_MAX` is returned (according to the return type and sign of the value, if any), and the value of the macro `ERANGE` is stored in `errno`.

It is best not to call, and especially not to rely upon, any routine until you have read and understood its documentation. Especially when a routine is not behaving as you expect, read its documentation.

Comment: Actually that rather convoluted wording says `strtol` returns LONG_MAX or LONG_MIN for values outside the representable range, depending on the sign.  But in this case, LONG_MAX, as it is positive.

Answer (score 2):

According to the C Standard (7.22.1.4 The strtol, strtoll, strtoul, and strtoull functions)

> 8 The strtol, strtoll, strtoul, and strtoull functions return the
> converted value, if any. If no conversion could be performed, zero is
> returned. **If the correct value is outside the range of representable
> values, LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX, LLONG_MIN, LLONG_MAX, ULONG_MAX, or
> ULLONG_MAX is returned** (according to the return type and sign of the
> value, if any), and the value of the macro ERANGE is stored in errno.

These string literals `"ffffffffffffffff"` and `"8000000000000000"` interpreted as positive numbers can not be represented in an object of the signed type `long`

Answer (score 0):

The `long` type on your system seems to have 64 bits, with a maximum positive value of 2<sup>63</sup>-1 (`LONG_MAX` on your platform), represented in hex as `7fffffffffffffff`. Any value larger than this will cause `strtol` to return `LONG_MAX` and set `errno` to `ERANGE`.

This is what you observe for `ffffffffffffffff` and `8000000000000000`.

Note that the hex string can start have an optional prefix of `0x` or `0X`.

You can parse unsigned long values with `strtoul`, with a maximum value of 2<sup>64</sup>-1 (`ULONG_MAX` on your platform), represented in hex as `ffffffffffffffff`.